# How to include all categories in one blog view

Tags: django, view

I have 8 categories on my blog. I created view that will show only posts from choosen category. It works but i must create new view to every category. How can i include all categories in one view?

My models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons',
                              blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Categories')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
```

It is my view:

```
def sport(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__exact="sport").order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

You see, this view is only to category 'sport', to category 'politics' i have another view etc.

In my template simple for loop:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

line in url

```
url(r'^sport$', views.sport, name='sport'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a more dynamic approach. Instead of having a url for `/sport`, do something like `/categories/sport`, and have the last part be a variable that is passed into the view for further processing.

urls.py

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>.*)$', views.category, name='category'),
```

views.py

```
def category(request, category_name):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name=category_name)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This way the category name is passed into your view, you filter with it, and pass the results to the template in the same way as before. Alternatively, you may prefer to use ids instead of category names, which is a common way such filtering is done.

Comment: Hi thanks, it works, i only added word 'exact' like in my view because without it i get error 'Unsupported lookup '' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.'. And i decided to use id, but i think i will use slug in the future because it will look better in page address. Thank you ;)